# Android control a service by activity

Tags: android, service

For a chat application i need service which manages the communication between the user and the web service. I decided to use the usual Android service component.

I now how to to start the service, also i know how to send messages from the service to the activity, but how do i control the service from the activity?
E.g. the user sends a message, so i have to make the service to send e.g. http requests containing the message. Or the user wants to end a chat session, so the activity have to make the service to send a request containing a command to end the chat session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AIDL`
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

In AIDL, you can implement methods in service, and call those methods from activity through binder.

So in your case,1) Implement sendMessage(String msg) in service

2)Declare this method in aidl file and call from service

```
mService.sendMessage(msg);
```

EDIT without using AIDL:

Service class

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        LocalService getService(){
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    public int getRandomNumber()
    {
        return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }

}
```

Activity class

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mbound = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_binding);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_binding, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent,mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        if(mbound)
        {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mbound = false;
        }
    }
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection(){


        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder)service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mbound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mbound = false;

        }
    };

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(mbound)
        {
            int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
            Toast.makeText(this, "number: "+num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx i will check this, but AIDL i used for inter process communication   and this service will run in the same process as the main thread. Hopefully there is a more leight weight method

Comment: if they are running in same process, then no need to use AIDL, just create a service by extend service and implement its methods and call from activity like mService.sendMessage(msg)

Comment: check my edited answer, i am sure this is what you are looking for

Comment: Ah ok this looks nice and easy i will try this

Comment: Lets say i call `mService.sendMessage();` and in sendMessage i make a httprequest. Then i am getting an exceptionOnMainThread error, but a service should run in its own thread, so may calling directly a services method is not the correct way?! i wonder why theres nothing similar like interacting with intentservices

Comment: service will run in same process until you specify process attribute in manifest file, btw can you post code snippet and exception, its difficult to tell without code..

Comment: It was may mistake, when i read the docs about service i skipped or didnt realized that the service runs on main thread. This is pretty confusing to me because what is the use of a service without concurrency?! Eventually i solved it not using bind but startservice.

Comment: Yes, with bind in IPC, many client can access service at same time, so service needs to be thread safe.